# vim folds don't work when changing to new file

Tags: vim, neovim

If I open a file with `nvim` from the command line then it will appear with all the folds closed: `nvim foo.cpp`

Then, if I open another file `:find bar.cpp` then the folds won't appear, if I type `\za \zc ...`  the program throws the error `E490: No fold found`.

My init.vim:

```
...
set foldenable
...
```

Comment: Maybe something about the `foldmethod` option? Check its value in both cases (startup and `:find`): if the values are different, there may be something to look about it. In any case, `:set foldmethod=syntax` may be a good common value to test for this option

Comment: When opening a file it would set to `foldmethod` to `indent` and when opening another it would change it to `manual`. Solved by changing `setlocal` to `set` in init.vim, my bad for not noticing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some methods to save folds:

1. If `foldmethod` is set to `manual` then you can use Vim's sessions (`:help session`) to save folds. For example load the file `bar.cpp`. Then define some folds with `:fold`. Save the current session `:mks bar.vim`. Quit vim `:q`. Then open Vim as `vim -S bar.vim` (or alternatively open vim and run the command `:so bar.vim`).
2. Similar to method 1 but use `:mkview bar.vim` instead of `:mks bar.vim`. Quit Vim and edit the file `bar.cpp` then do `:loadview` or `:so bar.vim`.
3. Set `foldmethod`  to `marker` then edit `bar.cpp` and make the folds you want with `:fold`. The folding region will be enclosed by triple braces `{{{,}}}` as defined by `foldmarker` option. Now the folds will persist even after closing the file. This method does not require saving sessions or views.

Methods 1 and 2 assume `fold` is included in `sessionoptions` and `viewoptions`.